# mysql-server installation gives this error: useradd: existing lock file /etc/passwd.lock without a PID

Tags: server, mysql

After 3 to 4 hours of hard struggle I resolved this issue, but I am still curious about this

> /etc/passwd.lock

What is /etc/password.lock? What /etc/passwd.lock does?

And what I understood after looking into the documentations on ubuntu man this file contains users, groups and other applications passwords. Correct me if I am wrong. And why was mysql-server installation dependent on this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but not really there yet. The file you read about is the `/etc/passwd` file, not the `/etc/passwd.lock` file. `/etc/passwd` defines which user accounts are available on you machine, which group(s) they belong to and other things. Many, many years ago `/etc/passwd` also contained the account's passwords. But for security reasons those were relocated into the so called "shadow password system" (which is essentially another file with stricter permissions).

`/etc/passwd.lock` is, as the name suggests, a lock file. Lock files are meant to indicate that a ressource is used by somebody else at the moment and therefore isn't available for you. Lock files are quite common, they've even got a default directory to store them into, `/var/lock`.

Back to `/etc/password`: This file and many other files are essentially text files and you technically can edit them with any text editor. But you really shouldn't, because if you mess up, you can do a lot of damage with a simple typo. Therefore, there's a bunch of tools to edit those central configuration files that at least try to prevent the largest mistakes.

To edit the `/etc/passwd` and some other files, you should use the `vipw` command. On of the things that `vipw` does is that it locks the corresponding file. That's to make sure that no two users or applications are editing the config file at the same time. So if you edit a user account with `vipw`, the command creates the `/etc/passwd.lock` lock file, to indicate that `/etc/passwd` isn't available for changes at the moment. Then it applies the changes and deletes the lock file to lift the lock.

In your case something seems to have gone wrong and the lock file wasn't removed, for whatever reason. So, when you tried to install the MySQL server, it couldn't edit `/etc/passwd`, because the lock file essentially told it "this ressource is in use, try again later".

Finally, what does the MySQL server have to do with `/etc/passwd`? One of the basic concepts of Unix and therefore Linux systems is that they're multi-user systems. There are multiple user accounts, which have different permissions (it's a bit more complicated than that, but that's the gist of it). You probably already know about the `root` account and your user account. But on a typical system, there are quite some more accounts "under the hood". On the machine I'm writing this on, which is basically a vanilly Ubuntu desktop installation, `/etc/passwd` defines 42 user accounts.

Generally, different accounts are used to shield stuff from people who aren't meant to mess with it, or to define who can use something and who can't. The MySQL server is executed under its own `mysql` account, and many other services and daemons (web servers, mail servers etc.) do something similarily.

So, to sum things up, your scenario was as follows: The installation process for the MySQL tried to add its `mysql` account to `/etc/passwd`, but the existence of the lock file told it that it couldn't do that at the moment.